# Get lat&lng of the pincode Location using in android

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a in put as pin-code or zip-code and i have to find the place in android? we have find address to lat & long and lat & long to address in android...but how to obtain with postal..? other than Google API any other API available for this...

Comment: Refer to this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226721/obtain-the-latitude-and-longitude-using-the-pincode-on-google-maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Geocoder** for  transforming a street address or other description of a location into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate or **Reverse geocoding** is the process of transforming a (latitude, longitude) coordinate into a (partial) address

please see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

you can also use **yahoo weather api** where you can enter a zip code and get the **name of city** or **location**

refer this [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

Comment: the input is only zip-code not any name or address,i give zip -code in  Geocoder but it not working?any other way?